# How do i calculate a value from the ViewModel in Xamarin.Form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

```
public string Price
{
    get
    {   
        return $"{(double.Parse(Market) / double.Parse(Average)).ToString()}";
    }

    set
    {
        price = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Price)); 
    }
}
```

Where price and Price have to be string but it have to be calculate every time the item change from the picker

Answer (score 1):

store your values as the appropriate type - don't continually try to parse them from strings - this is inefficient and will just cause you problems

In your Picker's Selected method, just call UpdatePrice() to update the Price

```
private double price;

public double Price )
  get {
    return price;
  } 
  set {
    price = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Price");
  }
}

private UpdatePrice {
  Price = Market / Average;
}
```